# EventHandlers or Callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

I am new to C#. Now I have learned how to create custom events in the application.

I want to know why should we use callbacks? Events seem to be simpler than callbacks and there is no need for passing the delegates in the argument.

I have referred the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733743%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) and it has been mentioned

> An event is like an anonymous broadcast, while a call-back is like a
>   handshake

Please provide me some example for this statement. I am confused where to use callbacks and event handlers as I can't find any difference between them.

Comment: You shouldn't use callbacks.  You should use events, `Task<T>`, or `IObservable` (Rx), as appropriate.

Comment: @SLaks Can you provide me a simple scenario?

Comment: @SLaks Of using events instead of callbacks.

Comment: check this article its just part1 but you can check the other 7 parts,it explains with examples delegates callbacks asynchronous callback.....http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/explaining-delegates-in-c.aspx

Comment: An event maintains a list of handler functions to invoke when the event is raised, and external subscribers can freely subscribe and unsubscribe. Callbacks are usually associated with a single invocation of an operation. The callback is provided to each call and the callee signals the callback when appropriate. Tasks should be used instead of callbacks where possible, and you may want to use reactive extensions instead of events.

Comment: Thanks @Lee I presume that callbacks are used for one to one commnunication and events are for one to many communications..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The semantic difference between the two, and reason for the statement that has you puzzled is that there is in fact a difference between a callback and an event, *semantically*.

Technically you implement them pretty much the same way, so let me explain.

A callback is when the contract of the code you're calling expects you to provide somewhere for it to call back, to report progress, to say it is done, or whatever it is it needs to inform you of.

It's like you call the library and ask them to find a book for you, and then *call you back* once they do. You expect the call to come. Additionally, the library does not tell people about books they find unless explicitly being asked to do so. If they find a different book on or behind the shelf, don't expect them to call you (or anyone else) because of this.

An event, on the other hand, is "an anonymous broadcast", akin to shouting in the woods. You're basically saying "If anyone cares, X just happened". You have not been explicitly told to call anyone before this, nor might you know who will listen.

Technically, in your code, you will implement both by passing a delegate to a method, or hooking on to an event (which is storing a delegate to a method), so in this respect they're two sides of the same coin, but their *meaning* is different.

Generally, events feel more "C#-ish", and are usually a bit easier to deal with, but both things have their place in the programming language and your toolbox.

Comment: Thanks @Lasse V.Karlsen and the example is awesome!!1